# how to use Espresso with Kotlin Flow?

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing, kotlin-flow

In my app I use Kotlin Flow. Before I used suspend function with  `EspressoIdlingResource.increment()`, but it does not work with Kotlin Flow. How to solve this problem?

Comment: EspressoIdlingResource.increment() supposed to tell framework to wait until some background operation is done. But I use Flows and Espresso finishes it checks immediately without waiting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've replicated your problem and then made it work.

I needed to add in your gradle the `espresso-idling-resource` lib in `implementation` and `androidTestImplementation`:

```
implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.3.0'
```

This way I could create in my project the `CountingIdlingResourceSingleton` object:

```
object CountingIdlingResourceSingleton {

    private const val RESOURCE = "GLOBAL"

    @JvmField val countingIdlingResource = CountingIdlingResource(RESOURCE)

    fun increment() {
        countingIdlingResource.increment()
    }

    fun decrement() {
        if (!countingIdlingResource.isIdleNow) {
            countingIdlingResource.decrement()
        }
    }
}
```

Then you should call this in your code when you want the test to wait, in my case it was in the `onViewCreated()` of the first fragment shown:

```
CountingIdlingResourceSingleton.increment()
```

And when the first flow element arrived I just called:

```
CountingIdlingResourceSingleton.decrement()
```

And finally add this in your test class to make it wait until the countingIdlingResource is decremented:

```
init {
    IdlingRegistry.getInstance()
            .register(CountingIdlingResourceSingleton.countingIdlingResource)
}

@After
fun unregisterIdlingResource() {
    IdlingRegistry.getInstance()
            .unregister(CountingIdlingResourceSingleton.countingIdlingResource)
}
```

With this the test that checked that the value matches the first value returned by flow (Jody) works.

A working example can be find in [github.com/jeprubio/waitflow](https://github.com/jeprubio/waitflow) where a flow element is emitted every 5 secs and the espresso test waits until the first element is emitted which is when the CountingIdlingResourceSingleton is decremented.